# How do I make ViewBag display class' property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core-mvc, dapper

I have two Models (Ninja & Dojo).

They are one to many relationship(Ninja belongs to One Dojo while Dojo can have many Ninjas).

I am using Dapper.

Ninja.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using dojoleague.Models;
using System;

namespace dojoleague.Models {
public class Ninja : BaseEntity{

    [Key]
    public long Id {get; set;}

    [Required(ErrorMessage="You need a name!")]
    public string Name {get; set;}

    [Range(1,11, ErrorMessage="Must be between 1 and 10")]
    public int Level {get; set;}

    [Required]
    public Dojo Dojo {get; set;}

    public string Description {get; set;}


  }
}
```

Ninjafactory:

```
public IEnumerable<Ninja> FindAll() 
{ 
    using (IDbConnection dbConnection = Connection) 
    { 
        dbConnection.Open(); 
        return dbConnection.Query<Ninja>("SELECT * FROM ninjas"); 
    } 
}
```

Dojo.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace dojoleague.Models {
public class Dojo : BaseEntity{

    [Key]
    public long Id {get; set;}

    [Required]
    public string Name {get; set;}

    [Required(ErrorMessage="We have to know where it is")]
    public string Location {get; set;}

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Provide additional info on the Dojo")]
    public string Description {get; set;}

     public ICollection<Ninja> Ninjas { get; set; }

}
}
```

In my controller,

I have:

```
 ninjaFactory.Add(newNinja, dojo);
 System.Console.WriteLine(newNinja.Dojo.Name);
 ViewBag.Ninja = ninjaFactory.FindAll();
 return View();
```

Now, System.Console.WriteLine(newNinja.Dojo.Name) correctly prints out Dojo's name in the console.

However, it does not show the Dojo's name on my web browser.

In my cshtml,

```
@{
  foreach(var ninja in ViewBag.Ninja){
      <h2>@ninja.Name</h2>
      <h4>@ninja.Dojo.Name</h4>
   }
 }
```

It does print out @ninja.Name but it doesn't print out @ninja.Dojo.Name saying

RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

How do I make the attribute of the Dojo class that belongs to Ninja class show using ViewBag??

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Can you write your `ninjaFactory.FindAll()` method?

Comment: public IEnumerable<Ninja> FindAll()
            {
                using (IDbConnection dbConnection = Connection)
            {
                   dbConnection.Open();
                   return dbConnection.Query<Ninja>("SELECT * FROM ninjas");
            }
        }

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVC or viewbag. The error message explains what's wrong. The `Dojo` property at least is *null*. *Is* there a `Dojo` to display? What does the data look like?

Comment: It would be a lot easier to debug this problem if you *didn't* use a ViewBag. Return the "ninjas" as the model, ie `var ninjas=ninjaFactory.FindAll();return View(ninjas);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with this code. Dojos aren't loaded and you don't handle Ronins (ninjas/samurais without Dojos/masters).

As @peinearydevelopment explains, Dapper doesn't load related objects automatically like full-featured ORMs. You'll have to return both objects in a single row, eg with a JOIN and use [multi-mapping](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper#multi-mapping) to map different fields to different objects.

You can write :

```
var sql ="SELECT * FROM ninjas inner join Dojos on Ninjas.DojoID=Docos.ID";
dbConnection.Query<Ninja, Dojo, Ninja>(sql, (ninja, dojo) => 
    { 
        ninja.Dojo = dojo; 
        return ninja;
    });
```

An even better option would be to create a *View* that returns Ninjas with Dojos, and map to it, eg :

```
var sql ="SELECT * FROM ninjasWithDojos ...";
dbConnection.Query<Ninja, Dojo, Ninja>(sql, (ninja, dojo) => 
    { 
        ninja.Dojo = dojo; 
        return ninja;
    });
```

The other part of the problem is that a Ninja may not *have* a Dojo. You won't even be able to load such entries if you use an inner join. You can load Ronins by using a left outer join :

```
var sql ="SELECT * FROM ninjas left outer join Dojos on Ninjas.DojoID=Docos.ID";
```

In this case you have to change your MVC View loop to ignore nulls. You can check the Dojo and remove the header entirely, or render a different snippet :

```
@foreach(var ninja in Model.Ninja)
{
    <h2>@ninja.Name</h2>
    @if (ninja.Dojo != null)
    {       
       <h4>@(ninja?.Dojo?.Name)??"Ronin!"</h4>
    }
}
```

Notice that I use `Model` instead of `ViewBag`. It's a lot easier to write and debug a strongly typed view. You can return the ninjas directly from your controller  :

```
//Controller
 var ninjas= ninjaFactory.FindAll();
 return View(ninjas);

//View
@model IEnumerable<Ninja>


@foreach(var ninja in Model)
```

Or as part of a ViewModel class :

```
 var ninjas= ninjaFactory.FindAll();
 var villains = ...;
 var game = new GameModel { Ninjas = ninjas, Villains = villains};
 return View(game);

//View
@model GameModel


@foreach(var ninja in Model.Ninjas)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper#multi-mapping), it would seem you need to update your query to this:
`var sql = 
@"select * from #Ninjas n 
left join #Dojos d on d.Id = n.DojoId 
Order by n.Id";`

`return dbConnection.Query<Post, Dojo>(sql, (ninja, dojo)=> { ninja.Dojo = dojo; return ninja;});`

Comment: The docs say that you need to return the `Dojos` as well in a join

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yup, I forgot to include the actual sql query. Updated, Thanks!